# How to use relative Xpath in Selenium webdriver in C# with VS

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am working on the automation project with our website.
There is an input box i need to pass the message to it, but the absolute Xpath looks always changes, so i cannot use it.

The relative Xpath like this

```
//*[@id="_ariaId_129"]/div/div/div[1]/div/span/div/form/input
```

the absoulate Xpath like this

```
/html/body/div[13]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/span/div/form/input
```

If i use it inside of the VS, it always gives me an error message in VS is i used relative Xpath copy from Chrome.

[image: Error message of relative Xpath in VB]

If i use Absolute Xpath, it works, but as i said, it may change next time when i test it.

Can someone help me to see what is the right format for use relative Xpath in VS? I tried writing it like below, none of them work. I tried to change "" to '' in Xpath, no error in VS, but cannot locate the element.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id="_ariaId_129"]/div/div/div[1]/div/span/div/form/input")]
```

or`[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@id='_ariaId_129']")]`

Comment: well, in order to help with xpath we need to see HTML you are trying to create xpath for

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one input under the parent element (The one with the Id) you could easily just use:

//*[@id="_ariaId_129"]//input

If that is not the case, then you'll have to find an id closer to what you want to select, or add one directly to the input you want to interact with.

For the screenshot with your error, it is because you have double quotes that are not escaped. You would have to do something like so:

"//*[@id=\"_ariaId_129\"]//input"

OR

"//*[@id='_ariaId_129']//input"